# Is there a difference between 'span :first' and 'span:first' in JQuery Selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Could someone tell me the difference between those two. The first one is working on FF and not in IE (6) and second one is working in IE (6) and not in FF (I am using the Jquery 1.4.2). We had to detect the browser and write the script accordingly.

Comment: On a side note, jQuery is written in such a way that almost all browser incompatibility is hidden in the libraries (because targeting browsers is bad). If you have to hack around that, there's something seriously wrong and you may want to refactor.

Comment: @Joseph: Totally agree with you. Usually I don't go for a hack but in this case I didn't know how to fix it since it works fine in FF but works rather weird in IE (6 alone). After doing that it works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One has a descendant selector in the middle of it.

```
span:first
```

Will select "All span elements that the :first pseudo-class applies to"

```
span :first
```

Will select "All elements which have the :first pseudo-class applied to them AND which are descended from a span element"

<del>There isn't actually a :first pseudo-class though. You might mean :first-child, :first-line or :first letter.</del>

(Oh, `:first` is some jQuery specific stuff, that explains why [SelectOracle](http://gallery.theopalgroup.com/selectoracle/) didn't know about it)

Comment: totally makes sense. So if I have to find the first span inside a given div & remove it then all I have to do is $("#divTest span first-child").remove(). Am I correct?

Comment: No, since (a) That would be a `<first-child>` element in a `<span>` etc and (b) `span:first-child` would be a span if it was the first child, not the first span. (You might want first-child, but it isn't what you had originally)